printing pdf using gsprint , output is cropped a little on sides and extra empty space at top
I am running windows 11 pro OS
In command prompt I ran following command to print a pdf file on printer.
"C:\Program Files\Ghostgum\gsview\gsprint.exe" -printer "EPSON TM-T82X Receipt"  PDFFile.pdf -ghostscript "C:\Program Files (x86)\gs\gs10.03.0\bin\gswin32c.exe"

The paper that came out is is half empty at top . 
Content is on bottom half and a little content on right and left sides is missing on paper output. 
Then I ran the following command to debug the issue
"C:\Program Files\Ghostgum\gsview\gsprint.exe" -sDEVICE=display  -dPDFFitPage PDFFile.pdf -ghostscript "C:\Program Files (x86)\gs\gs10.03.0\bin\gswin32c.exe" -debug
Copyright (C) 2003-2006, Ghostgum Software Pty Ltd.  All Rights Reserved.
2006-02-24 gsprint 1.9
Options:
 Colour=0
 Orientation=0
 Duplex=0
 Copies=0
 From=0
 To=0
 Even/Odd=0
 Twoup=0
 Query=0
 Printer=0
 Printer Name=""
 Ghostscript="C:\Program Files (x86)\gs\gs10.03.0\bin\gswin32c.exe"
 Ghostscript Options=" "-sDEVICE=display" "-dPDFFitPage""
 Document: "PDFFile.pdf"
DevNames:
 Device="EPSON TM-T82X Receipt"
 Driver="winspool"
 Output="Ne05:"
DevMode:
 dmDeviceName="EPSON TM-T82X Receipt"
 dmFields=0x580ef43
  DM_ORIENTATION
  DM_PAPERSIZE
  DM_COPIES
  DM_DEFAULTSOURCE
  DM_PRINTQUALITY
  DM_COLOR
  DM_YRESOLUTION
  DM_TTOPTION
  DM_COLLATE
 dmOrientation=1
 dmPaperSize=124
 dmPaperLength=2970
 dmPaperWidth=800
 dmScale=100
 dmCopies=1
 dmDefaultSource=15
 dmPrintQuality=203
 dmColor=1
 dmDuplex=1
 dmYResolution=203
 dmTTOption=3
 dmCollate=1
 dmFormName="Roll Paper 80 x 297 mm"
 dmLogPixels=0
 dmBitsPerPel=0
 dmPelsWidth=0
 dmPelsHeight=0
 dmDisplayFlags=1
 dmDisplayFrequency=0
PHYSICALWIDTH=639
PHYSICALHEIGHT=2373
PHYSICALOFFSETX=30
PHYSICALOFFSETY=0
HORZRES=577
VERTRES=2372
LOGPIXELSX=203
LOGPIXELSY=203
 Command: "C:\Program Files (x86)\gs\gs10.03.0\bin\gswin32c.exe" -sDEVICE=bmpmono -dNOPAUSE -g639x2373 -r203x203 -sOutputFile=%handle%0000027c "-sDEVICE=display" "-dPDFFitPage" -c "<< /.HWMargins [10.6404 0 11.3498 0.35468] >> setpagedevice" -f "PDFFile.pdf" -c quit
GPL Ghostscript 10.03.0 (2024-03-06)
Copyright (C) 2024 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software is supplied under the GNU AGPLv3 and comes with NO WARRANTY:
see the file COPYING for details.
Processing pages 1 through 1.
Page 1

Please see above output and guide me.
Let me know , if any information is needed .
Thanks.

Please point out scope for improvement if you downvote this .
